# sqlplus : stop displaying information about connection and disconnection

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Each time I start a new sql script in sqlplus (Oracle) I receive such an output:

```
 [exec] Connected to:
     [exec] Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
     [exec] With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
     [exec] and Real Application Testing options
     [exec]
     [exec]
     [exec] PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
     [exec]
     [exec] SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
     [exec] With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
     [exec] and Real Application Testing options
```

I'd like to get only information which is in the middle, namely:

```
     [exec] PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Is it possible to do it somehow ?

Btw. I know the -S option but it prevents me from displaying the SQL command which is going to be executed in next step. With -S those settings:

```
set serveroutput on size 1000000;
set echo on;
```

don't work.

Comment: No, sql*plus gives you all-or-nothing option. You either keep banner, command prompt and echoing of commands by starting sqlp*plus without `-s` option, or none of them by starting sqlp*lus  with `-s` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SPOOL command to write the output to a file, ECHO works in this case.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
SET ECHO ON
SPOOL logfile.txt
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the -s (silent) switch of sqlplus